# Why is $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{n^p}\right)}{\frac{1}{n^p}}\right)=1$ ？

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{n^p}\right)}{\frac{1}{n^p}}\right)=1\ (p>0)$$
When it is converted to 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n^p\sin \left(\frac{1}{n^p}\right)$$ which doesn't make it simple to evaluate the value, how to find the limit?

Comment: Where does p belongs ?

Comment: Do you know that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$?

Comment: To have the limit to be $1$ you must suppose $p>0$.

Comment: Also $|\sin(x)|\leq 1$  and  $$\sin(x)\leq |x|$$

Comment: See the article I mention in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $p>0$ put $x=\frac{1}{n^p}$ then $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{sin\left(\frac{1}{n^p}\right)}{\frac{1}{n^p}}\right)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{sin(x)}{x}=1$$
For a nice proof see [this article](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/1.-differentiation/part-a-definition-and-basic-rules/session-8-limits-of-sine-and-cosine/MIT18_01SCF10_Ses8a.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

$\dfrac1{n^p}$ tends to zero and you can use a change of variable,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{n^p}\right)}{\frac{1}{n^p}}\right)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}x=1.$$

Comment: Same answers! :)

Comment: Same truth :) Our posts crossed.

Comment: You just use L'Hôpital rule.

Comment: why?$\lim_{x→0} sin(x)/x=1$

Comment: @canoe For people who hate typology ,lol

Comment: @canoe: unfortunately, I can't answer that without knowing how your course is organized and how the trigonometric functions are introduced, because there is no single way to establish that limit.

Comment: @canoe See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1) for some common proofs.